# ASP.net validation: why do my DateTime fields also flag up as required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I'm implementing validation in my web app... the problem is it seems to be over-validating?!

The controller code looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authentication]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] CaseInfo caseInfo)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SetupViewData();
        return View();
    }

    _repository.Create(caseInfo);
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

This is the CaseInfo implementation:

```
public class CaseInfo :IValidatableObject
{   
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReferralDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int Decision { get; set; }
    public virtual string Reason { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And my CaseInfoMap:

```
public sealed class CaseInfoMap : ClassMap<CaseInfo>
{
    public CaseInfoMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ReferralDate);
        Map(x => x.Decision);
        Map(x => x.Reason);
        Map(x => x.StartDate);
        Map(x => x.EndDate);
    }
}
```

But when I run it up and submit the form with no values, I get the following validation errors:

```
# The ReferralDate field is required.
# The StartDate field is required.
# The EndDate field is required.
```

But I haven't specified that these *should* be required?!!  And why aren't the decision and reason fields throwing similar validation errors?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I'm using .NET 4, and MVC 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you change this:

```
public virtual DateTime ReferralDate { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual DateTime? ReferralDate { get; set; }
```

You need to use nullable type for DateTime.

If you want to do the same for all other dates change them:

> ```
> public class CaseInfo :IValidatableObject {        
>     public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }     
>     public virtual DateTime? ReferralDate { get; set; }     
>     public virtual int Decision { get; set; } 
>     public virtual string Reason { get; set; }     
>     public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }     
>     public virtual DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }      
>     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>
> ```
>
> Validate(ValidationContextvalidationContext)
>   {throw new NotImplementedException();}
>       }

Check the MSDN documentation on datetime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=VS.90).aspx

You will notice that the values have a range, which do not include null, hence your validator fails.  You will want to use the datetime nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime struct is not nullable, so it is in-effect required. You should use a `Nullable<DateTime>` [or `DateTime?` for the shorthand] if it is nullable.